# Error with adding page in layout links portion of chapter 5 (Michael Hartl)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec-rails, railstutorial.org

I am in section 5.3 in Michael Hartl's RoR tutorial, where I am adding a Contact Page.  I ran `$ bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb`.  I cannot figure out the error.  I made changes in spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb, as well as added the appropriate route, action for the contact page and edited the view for the contact page.  This is the output:

```
Failures:

  1) Static Pages Contact page should have the h1 'Contact'
 Failure/Error: visit '/static_pages/contact'
 ActionView::Template::Error:
   /Users/themaktravels/rails_projects/happy_app/app/views/static_pages/contact.html.erb:1: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
   ...putBuffer.new; provide (:title, 'Contact') 
   ...                               ^
   /Users/themaktravels/rails_projects/happy_app/app/views/static_pages/contact.html.erb:1: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
   ...ew; provide (:title, 'Contact') 
   ...                               ^
 # <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
 # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:56:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Static Pages Contact page should have the title 'Contact'
 Failure/Error: visit '/static_pages/contact'
 ActionView::Template::Error:
   /Users/themaktravels/rails_projects/happy_app/app/views/static_pages/contact.html.erb:1: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
   ...putBuffer.new; provide (:title, 'Contact') 
   ...                               ^
   /Users/themaktravels/rails_projects/happy_app/app/views/static_pages/contact.html.erb:1: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
   ...ew; provide (:title, 'Contact') 
   ...                               ^
 # <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
 # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:61:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.53514 seconds
9 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:55 # Static Pages Contact page should have the h1 'Contact'
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:60 # Static Pages Contact page should have the title 'Contact'
```

In `static_pages_spec.rb`, I have following:

```
 describe "Contact page" do

     it "should have the h1 'Contact'" do
     visit '/static_pages/contact'
     page.should have_selector('h1', :text => 'Contact')
end

     it "should have the title 'Contact'" do
     visit '/static_pages/contact'
     page.should have_selector('title',
       :text => "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Happy App | Contact")
end
```

In the RoR tutorial, this is what you are instructed to have in `static_pages_spec.rb`:

```
 describe "Contact page" do

     it "should have the h1 'Contact'" do
     visit '/static_pages/contact'
     page.should have_selector('h1', text: 'Contact')
  end

     it "should have the title 'Contact'" do
     visit '/static_pages/contact'
     page.should have_selector('title',
                text: "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Contact")
  end
```

The only changes I made in `static_pages_spec.rb` were (1) make "Sample App" to "Happy App" and (2) "text:" was used instead of ":text =>", so that the format was consistent throughout the code in `static_pages_spec.rb`.  When troubleshooting, I switched between both "text" versions and got the same result.

Any suggestions on what I should be looking for to solve the error?  Also, I am unsure of how to read the error message, i.e. does the first section of the error show the proper method or vice versa?

Thank you!

Comment: What does your **app/views/static_pages/contact.html.erb** view file look like?  As the error states, it looks like you have a syntax error.

Comment: <% provide (:title, 'Contact') %>
  <h1>Contact</h1>
  <p>
 Contact Ruby on Rails Tutorial About the Happy App at the 
 <a href="http://railstutorial.org/contact">contact page</a>.
  </p>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have an unnecessary space on your provide line.  It should be

```
<% provide(:title, 'Contact') %>
```

not

```
<% provide (:title, 'Contact') %>
```

Comment: Thank you.  I was looking at this so long that I didn't even see that extra space.